# How to allow specified resources to be viewed before a user is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I would like to allow users to view properties before they are logged in. But my application controller is restricting all resources before they are logged in. How can I allow the properties resource to be viewed regardless of whether a user being logged in or not?

I've tried adding the properties to the `authorized` method in `application_controller` and adding `skip_before_action :authorized, only: [:index]`
 and `authorize!` in the `properties_controller`.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    before_action :authorized

  def encode_token(payload)
    # should store secret in env variable
    JWT.encode(payload, 'SECRET_KEY_BASE')
  end

  def auth_header
    request.headers['Authorization']
  end

  def decoded_token
    if auth_header
      token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
      begin
        JWT.decode(token, 'SECRET_KEY_BASE', true, algorithm: 'HS256')
      rescue JWT::DecodeError
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  def current_investor
    if decoded_token
      investor_id = decoded_token[0]['investor_id']
      @investor = Investor.find_by(id: investor_id)
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_investor
  end

  def authorized
    render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

```rb
class Api::V1::PropertiesController < ApplicationController

    def index 
        properties = Property.all
        render json: PropertySerializer.new(properties).to_serialized_json
    end

    def create
        property = Property.new(property_params)
        if property.save!
            render json: property_params
        else
            render :new 
        end
    end

    private 

    def property_params
        params.require(:id, :price, :rent, :year_built, :last_year_appreciation, :next_year_appreciation, :lease_length, :beds_baths_sqft, :description, :zone, :address)
    end
end
```

I would like the whole properties resource be available regardless of a user being logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Api::V1::PropertiesController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorized!
end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Answer (score 0):

skip_before_action :authorized, except: [:index]
Try this  will skip the authetication index method where properties can be visible to without logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the `ApplicationController` you are calling `before_action :authorized` so this will be called in every single `controller` that is `inherited` from `ApplicationController`.

So what i suggest you is to remove the `before_action filter` from `ApplicationController` and place it in the corresponding `controller`. So your code might look something like,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      def encode_token(payload)
    # should store secret in env variable
    JWT.encode(payload, 'SECRET_KEY_BASE')
  end

  def auth_header
    request.headers['Authorization']
  end

  def decoded_token
    if auth_header
      token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
      begin
        JWT.decode(token, 'SECRET_KEY_BASE', true, algorithm: 'HS256')
      rescue JWT::DecodeError
        nil
      end
    end
  end

  def current_investor
    if decoded_token
      investor_id = decoded_token[0]['investor_id']
      @investor = Investor.find_by(id: investor_id)
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_investor
  end

  def authorized
    render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
  end
end
```

And in your `PropertiesController` You can do something like this so that `authorized` method will not be called for the `index` action.

```
class Api::V1::PropertiesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorized, only: [:create]

    def index 
        properties = Property.all
        render json: PropertySerializer.new(properties).to_serialized_json
    end

    def create
        property = Property.new(property_params)
        if property.save!
            render json: property_params
        else
            render :new 
        end
    end

    private 

    def property_params
        params.require(:id, :price, :rent, :year_built, :last_year_appreciation, :next_year_appreciation, :lease_length, :beds_baths_sqft, :description, :zone, :address)
    end
end
```